# What are the drag & drop patterns for iPhone 5 or 6?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, apple

I'm working on a design for an iPhone app that drags & drops pictures from one place to the other, something similar to the screenshot below. I downloaded a few of the most popular picture apps (Flickr, Carousel, Shoebox) but none of them have this drag & drop feature.

- What are some existing patterns could I use?
- Where is the research about whether drag & drop is a recommended mobile experience?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: This is the right place to ask if you can rephrase it  a bit. If you ask for reasons and sources that explain why or why not to implement drag and drop on mobile devices, you will get less answers based on guesses.

Comment: One app I can think of that allows drag/dropping of files is iStorage, and it shows well why it is more of a gimmick than actually useful: There is simply not enough space. But it's not said this counts for every app and (not) doing something because others do(n't) is a never a good argument.

Comment: It's likely a size issue. Dragging and dropping on small screens can be a fiddly process.

Comment: If you look at design application like Procreate & Pixelmator those have some nice drag and drops. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Referring the iOS HIG, Dragging is a design principle, however, it isn't used as often in iOS as it is being in the competitive mobile OSes.

Mainly, iOS functions with Multi Select > Action.

Drag and Drop requires a considerable screen estate which might not be enough for screen sizes from 4.7 inches to 5 inches.

I've however seen Drag and Drop used in iPads. Works great in that.

Answer (score 1):

A good example of drag+drop pattern is the iPhone home screen interface which allows you to drag and rearrange apps or drag and group apps into folders: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT200290

#### Why its not popular

In many cases apps allow **horizontal swiping** or **vertical scrolling**, which automatically limits a lost of simple gestures to be used for dragging. Many applications rely on "**tap+hold**" to activate dragging. That gesture may not even fire if the device assumes you were scrolling or swiping or tapping, which could be frustrating.

#### Potential Solution

If your app does not have a need to use swiping or scrolling gestures, I don't see why you wont be able to use "**tap+move**".

I also found an article [Touch-friendly Drag and Drop](https://mobiforge.com/design-development/touch-friendly-drag-and-drop) which you may find helpful to achieve what you want.